# Solving System of Congruence using Chinese Remainder Theorem

Tags: inverse, congruences, chinese-remainder-theorem

I'm trying to solve a system of congruence using CRT

$$x≡2\pmod3\\
x≡3\pmod5\\
x≡2\pmod7$$

My approach is

First calcuating $m_1,m_2,m_3$ then M followed by inverses of $m_1,m_2$ and $m_3$ and finally applying to the formulae for $x=(a_1\cdot m_1\cdot m_1 inv+.....)$

How is the multiplicative inverse of $m_1$ found eg: in this case $m_1=35$. How is $m_1$ inv  calculated?

Comment: Modulo $3$, $35$ is congruent to $2$. The inverse is $2$. For large numbers, we would need something like the extended Euclidean Algorithm to calculate the modular inverses.  But it seems likely that for this exercise you are expected to do it by inspection.

Comment: I did not understand what you meant to say.What does Modulo 3, 35 is congruent to 2 mean?

Comment: @techno It means $35\equiv 2\pmod{3}$

Comment: @ChristopherToni Im a complete noob when it comes to maths where does this 3 come from?

Comment: The three primes are $3,5,7$. For CRT, you need the inverse of $35$ modulo $3$, the inverse of $21$ modulo $5$, the inverse of $15$ modulo $7$. The last two are easiest. For note for example that $21\equiv 1\pmod{5}$, so the inverse of $21$ modulo $5$ is $1$. Similarly, the inverse of $15$ modulo $7$ is $1$. For the inverse of $35$ modulo $3$, note that $35=(3)(11)+2$, so modulo $3$, $35$ is "the same thing" as $2$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas One more question consider 5X≡11(mod3) Can i write it as X≡11*5^Φ(3)-1 (mod 3)

Comment: The Euler $\phi$-function (in this case Fermat's Theorem) is not a great tool for finding inverses. But yes, the solution to $5x\equiv 11\pmod{4}$ can be written as $x\equiv(11)(5^{(\varphi(3)-1)})\pmod{3}$.  I worry that you may be thinking a little too mechanically in terms of formulas, without sufficient intuitive idea of what's going on.

Comment: @AndréNicolas  i need to pass my exam :) and its tommorow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, $x^{-1} \pmod{y}$ is defined as: $x^{-1}*x \equiv x*x^{-1}\equiv1 \pmod{y}$

The solution of the problem can be made as:

$x=3a+2=5b+3=7c+2$

Take $3a+2=7c+2 \implies 3a=7c$

Take Least Common Multiple $\operatorname{lcd}[3,7]=21$

Then, $x=21k+2$ for some $k$.

Now, $21k+2=5b+3 \implies 21k=5b+1 \implies 21k\equiv1 \pmod{5}\implies k\equiv 1 \mod{5}$ $\implies k=5n+1$

Then the solution we're looking for is:

$x=21(5n+1)+2=23+105n, n\in \mathbb{N}$